# How to implement drag and drop image?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

how would you implement a function so that users can upload their images and then drag and drop them in the order they would like to present their photos? I'm using the ROR framework. Gems perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to put the images in a list and give each li a data-attribute with it's image id, like:

```
<ul>
    <li data-image_id="1"><img src="/image1.png" /></li>
    <li data-image_id="2"><img src="/image2.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

Then write some nice JavaScript code (you could use Jquery plugins like http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/) and use the callbacks for the end of the dragging. In the callback you write a little code that loops the list, parses the data-image_id values and sends this data back to the server for further processing (by storing the 'position' as INT in the database for example).

Ps. I would advice to use the position field DESC so that new images, with 0/null as position, automatically end up as last one in the row. Your client will be thrilled not having to re-arrange all images after they added 4 new images to a carefully ordered set.